# Display bytes as images on an .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html, image

I'm using a database to store clients' images as bytes. How can I render these images on an .aspx page?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Two solutions.

1. Build a handler page. That takes an ImageID/RowID as GET parameter and returns data with mimetype image/jpeg or image/png.
2. Use DATA uri scheme as explained on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

   <img src="data:image/png;base64,
   iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
   C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
   AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
   REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
   ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
   vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />

Comment: Nice.. I'd never heard of the DATA uri sheme.  +1 to you.  That's why I love this site.. Something new every day...

Comment: @david - even I knew very late in my career. i had belief only file paths are allowed there.

Comment: @ankit +1, ditto @David. Never heard of it; will solve a big, huge problem for me: pre-downloading png images. CSS classes that incorporate base-64-encoded images will (I think!) be much quicker, more reliable, and more repeatable than other well-known but imo somewhat ugly, hackish pre-downloading schemes.

Comment: @lcplben.. ooh ya. this is ugly as these images are never cached and travel with page content. Not good for bigger images. And do not use second method for the sake of PRE-LOADING images.

Comment: @Ankit thanks for reply..is we have to use data:image/png;base64 for every image byte array?

Comment: here is what I am trying to  System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            investorLogo.Src = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", enc.GetString(investor.Logo));

but its rendering all bytes

Answer (score 2):

Instructions can be found here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

in step 4, but the whole article is worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily by converting the Byte Array to a Base64 image.

```
public string GetImageAsBase64String(byte[] bin)
{
    if (bin != null)
    {
        return "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bin) + "\">";
    }
    else
    {
       return null;
    }
}

//usage, for demo purposes an uploaded image from a FileUpload Control
Label1.Text = GetImageAsBase64String(FileUpload1.FileBytes);
```